# Prestashop Module Function execution

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

i am trying to create a button in the backoffice order details page that when i click it it adds some data in the db but it seems that the function actually runs when i open the order details page instead of when i click the button in the order details page

```
public function hookActionGetAdminOrderButtons(array $params)
{
    other code.....


    /** @var \PrestaShopBundle\Controller\Admin\Sell\Order\ActionsBarButtonsCollection $bar */
    $bar = $params['actions_bar_buttons_collection'];

    $bar->add(
        new \PrestaShopBundle\Controller\Admin\Sell\Order\ActionsBarButton(
            'btn-secondary', ['href' => $this->addOrderTracking($id_order, $id_client, $client_name, $client_phone, $client_address, $client_email, $id_carrier)], 'Create Tracking Number'
        )
    );

}

private function addOrderTracking($id_order, $id_client, $client_name, $client_phone, $client_address, $client_email, $id_carrier): bool
{
    $query = [
        "INSERT INTO `"._DB_PREFIX_."eprim_tracking` (id_order, id_client, client_name, client_phone, client_address, client_email, id_carrier)
        VALUES ('$id_order', '$id_client', '$client_name', '$client_phone', '$client_address', '$client_email', '$id_carrier')"
    ];
    return $this->executeQueries($query);
}

private function executeQueries(array $queries): bool
{
    foreach ($queries as $query) {
        if (!Db::getInstance()->execute($query)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in this part of the code in the href:

```
$bar->add(
    new \PrestaShopBundle\Controller\Admin\Sell\Order\ActionsBarButton(
    'btn-secondary', ['href' => $this->addOrderTracking($id_order, $id_client, $client_name, $client_phone, $client_address, $client_email, $id_carrier)], 'Create Tracking Number'
    )
);
```

referencing function for the href is actually running the function once. it's not the correcy way to create a link for a function in the module.